# scale on z axis move

Tags: opengl, scale

At the position z = 0 my box has size on one side 0.2. When, for example, I move it to z = 1.5,  size of it scale up. I've trided to calculate it by using triangle formula z*tan(fov/2), but it does not really work.

Do you know how to get size of one side after primitive moved on z axis ?

(All about in opengl)

Comment: Are you looking for perspective projection?

Comment: Yes, I am looking perspective projection

Comment: Are you trying to find out the size of the object on the screen after it's been altered with perspective projection? I feel like you are trying to do something that has a simpler solution than calculating the perspective translation from a camera.

Comment: well, actually I am trying to implement my own RayTest, using for now just a simple rectangle (without rotations) for rigid body. and when I am putting it closer then calculating if world ray coordinate belongs to rectangle or not gives me incorrect result due to scaling effect